# Findbugs Detectors: Check Instantiation with a specific Cast?

Tags: java, findbugs

I'm putting together a findbugs detector to look for any HttpURLConnections being created in some java code. A big project has a ton, and can no longer perform unencrypted connections, so I would like to report them via findbugs.

I know I can use the following to check for new java.net.URL instantiations where I use "http://"

```
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.bcel.OpcodeStackDetector;
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.BugInstance;
import edu.umd.cs.findbugs.BugReporter;


public class UnencryptedHttpDetector extends OpcodeStackDetector {

     private BugReporter bugReporter;

        public UnencryptedHttpDetector(BugReporter bugReporter) {
            this.bugReporter = bugReporter;
        }


    @Override
    /***
     * Look for instantiation of HttpUrlConnection
     */
public void sawOpcode(int seen) {

    if ((seen == INVOKESPECIAL) &&  getClassConstantOperand().equals("java/net/URL") 
            && getNameConstantOperand().equals("<init>")
              ){

         OpcodeStack.Item top = stack.getStackItem(0);
         //Object value = top.getConstant();
         String value = top.getConstant().toString();
         if(value.toLowerCase().startsWith("http://"))
         {
                bugReporter.reportBug(new BugInstance(this, "HTTP_INSECURE_CONNECTION", NORMAL_PRIORITY)
                        .addClassAndMethod(this).addSourceLine(this));
         }
        }
    }
```

This will find my code, but how can I check for:

```
HttpURLConnection connection = (HttpURLConnection)new URL("http://www.google.com").openConnection();
```

Specifically, where the URL creation is cast to a `HttpURLConnection`?

Logging, I can see that I have a stack depth of 3. Can I check the return value from this init? I'm not sure how.

**Edit:**

I've gotten part of it, but basically I need to look at a CHECKCAST and throw up something when I am casting to HttpUrlConnection, or actually check the variable declaration.

My new method looks like:

```
@Override
/***
 * Look for instantiation of HttpUrlConnection
 */
public void sawOpcode(int seen) {
    //Check Invoking URL with a http:// url
    if ((seen == INVOKESPECIAL) &&  getClassConstantOperand().equals("java/net/URL") 
            && getNameConstantOperand().equals("<init>")
              ){

         OpcodeStack.Item top = stack.getStackItem(0);
         String value = top.getConstant().toString();
         if(value.toLowerCase().startsWith("http://"))
         {
                bugReporter.reportBug(new BugInstance(this, "HTTP_INSECURE_CONNECTION", NORMAL_PRIORITY)
                        .addClassAndMethod(this).addSourceLine(this));
         }
        }
    //Check Casting URLConnection to HttpURLConnection
    else if(seen == CHECKCAST && getClassConstantOperand().equals("java/net/HttpURLConnection"))
    {
         OpcodeStack.Item top = stack.getStackItem(0);
         if(top.getSignature().equals("java/net/URLConnection"))
         {
               bugReporter.reportBug(new BugInstance(this, "HTTP_INSECURE_CONNECTION", NORMAL_PRIORITY)
               .addClassAndMethod(this).addSourceLine(this));
         }

    }

}
```

And this checks for URL("Http://....") and casting URLConnection to HttpUrlConnection. Can I check for declaring a httpurlconnection?

Comment: I see that I get an INVOKEVIRTUAL and a CHECKCAST, and still working out how to check for them in the right order on the stack.